# How soon can I use newly cut sycamore logs?

Tags: trees

I've just cut down two large sycamores (*Acer pseudoplatanus*), leaving me with a considerable quantity of logs to use for other projects.

How soon can I use these logs for building, for example, a compost enclosure or trellis, without risk of them sprouting?

(Location: Western Europe, height of spring)

Answer (score 0):

I cut down a small American sycamore , butt end 8 in. diameter . I laid it on soil at the edge of a garden and it never sprouted.

Comment: This is Acer pseudoplatanus, the American sycamore is Platanus occidentalis, I'm not sure they're comparable